# Correct IDA PRO Control Flow Graph

Tags: ida

I'm analyzing a MIPS ELF executable with calls to the `exit()` function, however IDA PRO is not correctly recognizing the end of the block:

[image]

- **Question**: Is it possible to remove the blue arrow linking the `exit()` block with the next one ?
- **Question**: Is it possible to enhance the disassembly if IDA by specifying exit as a block end ?

Comment: Good luck on the NSC challenge ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is possible to define a function exit as "no return" function.
This should fix the problem.

To do it you should find exit function, right click on it, choose "edit function" and mark "Does not return" checkbox.